# Unflatten a dict obtained from JSON using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, flatten, spring-cloud-config

This JSON structure is from a Spring Cloud server config:

```
{
  "item[0].subitem[0].key": "value1",
  "item[0].subitem[1].key": "value2",
  "item[1].subitem[0].key": "value3",
  "item[1].subitem[1].key": "value4"
}
```

I have a Flask app which will consume that format, but I need to convert it to this format for further processing:

```
{
  "item": [
    {
      "subitem": [
        {
          "key": "value1"
        },
        {
          "key": "value1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "subitem": [
        {
          "key": "value1"
        },
        {
          "key": "value1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This problem is nice! I'll just provide a hint: `for k, v in input.items(): item, subitem, key = k.split('.') `

Comment: I don't think you will get a canned solution for this, I would try to follow Apalala's hint.

Comment: Note that, to preserve the semantics, you need Python >= 3.6, so insertion order is meaningful in `dict`. Otherwise the semantics in the original structure would be lost.

Comment: I've read frequently about _flattening_ in data processing libraries, @TomasZubiri, but I rarely come about an unflattening problem. Maybe there's a function for a one-liner somewhere.

Comment: @Apalala Your hint is not a hint at all since the fact that the data structure is a mix of nested dicts and lists makes it impossible to use simple unpacking like that for implementation.

Comment: @blhsing I solved the problem using a different version of the hint: `*keys, last_key = flatkey.split('.')`. I'm not sharing the solution only because the problem is hard, but the solution is simple,  which makes me want to keep the unsolved problem for other purposes.

Comment: I can provide another hint: [divide and conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm). First unflatten, then normalize the keys.

Comment: @Apalala Your so-called "hints" would solve only the dict part of the question but not the list part. The fact that you split with a `.` shows that you are not even trying to deal with the list indices at all.

Comment: @blhsing You are right in that I've assumed that the original data is always in the correct order. Yet the `split()` strategy will still work even if there has to be sorting on the indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below shows a generalized solution that includes more test cases than your requirement:

```
import re
j = {
  "item[0].subitem[0].key": "value1",
  "item[0].subitem[1].key": "value2",
  "item[1].subitem[0].key": "value3",
  "item[1].subitem[1].key": "value4",
  "item2[0].subitem[0]": "value5",
  "item2[0].subitem[1]": "value6",
  "item2[1][0].key1": "value7",
  "item2[1][1].key2": "value8"
}
d = {}
for key, value in j.items():
    s = d
    tokens = re.findall(r'\w+', key)
    for count, (index, next_token) in enumerate(zip(tokens, tokens[1:] + [value]), 1):
        value = next_token if count == len(tokens) else [] if next_token.isdigit() else {}
        if isinstance(s, list):
            index = int(index)
            while index >= len(s):
                s.append(value)
        elif index not in s:
            s[index] = value
        s = s[index]
```

`d` becomes:

```
{'item': [{'subitem': [{'key': 'value1'}, {'key': 'value2'}]},
          {'subitem': [{'key': 'value3'}, {'key': 'value4'}]}],
 'item2': [{'subitem': ['value5', 'value6']},
           [{'key1': 'value7'}, {'key2': 'value8'}]]}
```

Comment: The extra test cases are to show that this is a generalized code. Coding just for the `item[0].subitem[0].key` spec would not be any easier. Why don't you give it a try?

Comment: Keys like `item2` or `key2` are not in the original spec.

Comment: Which part of "The extra test cases are to show that this is a generalized code" do you not understand?

Comment: You are right @blhsing. Please edit so I can remove the downvote?

Comment: Sure. I've updated my answer to note that this is designed to be a generalized solution. Peace.

Comment: @blhsing I managed to solve the problem with two steps. with reduce function and a recursive function. But your solution seems to be the right one. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

or use a package made for this:

https://github.com/amirziai/flatten

`pip install flatten_json`

which support flattening and unflattening.

Comment: This looks great. Wish I'd come across it a few months ago.

Answer (score -1):

I explained why I don't want to provide a complete solution in the comments to the OP's question. This should be enough of a hint:

```
def main():
    input = {
        "item[0].subitem[0].key": "value1",
        "item[0].subitem[1].key": "value2",
        "item[1].subitem[0].key": "value3",
        "item[1].subitem[1].key": "value4",
    }
    items = list(input.items())
    random.shuffle(items)
    shuffled = dict(items)

    result = normalize_keys(unflatten(shuffled))

    print(json.dumps(result, indent=2))
```

Results in:

```
{
  "item": [
    {
      "subitem": [
        {
          "key": "value1"
        },
        {
          "key": "value2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "subitem": [
        {
          "key": "value3"
        },
        {
          "key": "value4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks but @blishng solution seems to fit all my test cases